# "Practical" references on mapping spaces as infinite-dimensional manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, smooth-manifolds, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

I am studying spaces of the form $C^{k}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ between manifolds ($k=\infty$ allowed) and I am looking for extensive references, especially analysing their topology and smooth structure.

I know that there are two choices of topologies, namely the "compact open $C^k$" and "Whitney $C^k$ topology“ and they agree in case $\mathcal{M}$ is compact. Furthermore, these spaces are Banach manifolds if $k$ finite. I am looking for references discussing these structures explicitly and in all the necessary details. I good book seems to be the second chapter of Hirsch's "Differential topology", but it is unfortunately rather short and he does not talk about the smooth structure of these spaces. The classical textbooks by Michor and Kriegl-Michor are also very nice, but I am looking for a more practical treatment, as these books are very abstract, i.e. they define the topologies using Jet bundles, which is of course interesting, but I would like to have a more "elementary" treatment, for example using charts or bases of these topologies, like in Hirsch.

Comment: I think you listed all the books on the subject. You may have to learn the language of jet bundles and how to translate to the language of charts. Hirsch does this fairly explicitly in chapter 2, section 4.

Comment: If you only care about mapping spaces as Banach manifolds, Lang's classic _Differential and Riemannian Manifolds_ (Springer, 1995) develops basic differential geometry in a way that applies to Banach manifolds. However, he mentions $C^k(M,N)$ spaces specifically only in passing.

Comment: "Introduction to global analysis" by Donald Kahn might be the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: That said, is there a particular reason why you are interested in the smooth structure?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Comment: @RyanBudney I was reading an article where the authors did things like defining curves in function spaces and taking their derivatives, or defining maps between function spaces and talking about their differential. So, I would like to understand the underlying theory a little bit better, since the authors do not define the structures and definitions around these spaces....